# FormResponse.getRespondentEmail() not working for G Suite user that has been renamed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

The below code runs on a user installed trigger "Form submit" of a Google Form.

It works alright for all G Suite users except for one user who has been renamed in G Suite. So this user has a new email address and the original email address of the user before renaming, is currently an alias. When this particular user submits the form, the variable "submitter" is null or an empty string.

Is this a known issue for the [FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail()) function?

Is there any workaround for this issue?

```
function onSubmit(e) {

  var emailBody = "";

  var response = e.response;
  var responseId = response.getId();
  var timeStamp = response.getTimestamp();
  var submitter = response.getRespondentEmail();

  }
```

Comment: Create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: As @TheMaster said, please go to [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) and fill up the template following the instructions shown there.

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster and alberto vielma. I have created an issue. The link to the issue is https://issuetracker.google.com/150247013